# TFS Project is visible in the Source control explorer but not in Team Explorer?

Tags: tfs

I'm able to view the project
1.from the Source Control Explorer but not in Team explorer,Only if i have open the local project which is binded to TFS Only then i can view the other folders within in TFS Project.
2.From Tfs command Line Utility
3.Suppose there are no workspaces and no projects downloaded from TFS then only way to view the project is from the command line Utility.

Is there any way fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the root in the team explorer pane, and select "Add existing team project". You should be able to select the new project from there.

Comment: I have tried that as well, and Its not visible over there which makes this very strange is it something to do with permissions.?

Comment: Possibly - have you spoken to your TFS administrator?

Comment: Yea, i guess i have to check with the TFS admin.

Comment: But the TFS command line is able to pull out the info about the project which i selected in the TFS server.If i execute this command
tf workspace /new /s:<servername> it shows the Workspace window and if try to choose the server project by default it brings me to the project which i selected before. How is it able to bring this information?

Comment: Looks like the project which i have selected is not visible, because when it shows the window for "Add existing team project" its not visible , so i just gave oK and in the source control explorer was populated with the project which i selected before.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a permissions issue.  I'm guessing you don't have permissions set up on the Team Project, but you do have read permissions on the source control.  Keep in mind that, though the two are related, they are stored and maintained separately in the back-end.